# WP7-How To Extend List Box When Reaching Last Item

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, wp7test

This web page give the idea about How To Extend List Box When Reaching Last Item [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

but in my case there are 2 or more list box in pivot. How to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `LongListSelector` (part of the [Windows Phone Toolkit on WP7](http://phone.codeplex.com/)) instead of a `Listbox`, infinite scrolling is a lot easier to implement...

http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx